# Output the binaries in the project's root bin subfolder using cmake

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm currently on a BF interpreter project. I decided to use CMake, and it works properly.
I settled for an out-of-source build, following the following tree :

```
+ Project root
|
+-- src/
+-- bin/
+-- build/ <- holds the "rubbish" generated by CMake when generating the Makefile
+-- CMakeLists.txt
```

When I want to build the project, I run, from the project's root folder :

```
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

In the CMakeLists.txt, I added the following line :

```
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
```

But, I've found it outputs the binaries in the build/bin folder, so I edited the line to :

```
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH "../bin/"
```

It works perfectly fine, but it is, IMHO, kind of ugly. Is there any "clean" way of doing this, that is without making assumptions about the project's structure, instead using something like `set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_ROOT}/bin")` ?
Thanks in advance for your replies and sorry for any English errors i may have made, as English isn't my first language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the variable [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#prop_tgt%3aRUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY) to achieve this - something like:

```
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
```

Basically, the `${PROJECT_ROOT}` variable you are looking for is [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR), [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_SOURCE_DIR), or [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR).  Each has a slightly different meaning, but for a basic project, these could well all point to the same directory.

Note that for the `CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY` variable to take effect, it must be set *before* the target is created, i.e. before the `add_executable` call in the CMakeLists.txt.

Also note that multi-configuration generators like MSVC will still append a per-configuration directory to this `project root/bin` folder.